# What is the difference between an ng-controller directive and a controller in the route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I worked through the [tutorial on the AngularJS website](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and I noticed that in at [step 7](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), they change how a controller is introduced into the application.  Initially, they use a directive:

```
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
...
</body>
```

However, it later gets changed to use a `controller` attribute as part of an `ng-route`.

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
    }). 
    /* rest of routes here */
```

Here's the [git diff](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/compare/step-6...step-7) where the change is made.  Is there a difference between these two techniques?

Comment: What is the link for the step you are on?

Comment: @qwertynl Step 7. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: possible duplicate of [specifying AngularJS controller: benefits using ngController vs. $routeProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696807/specifying-angularjs-controller-benefits-using-ngcontroller-vs-routeprovider)

Comment: @DanDascalescu I think my question came first.

Comment: @austin: I know, but unfortunately the other one has better answers.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I dunno, I think those answers are pretty subjective.  Both appeal to personal opinions.  At least this question has some source code and some objectivity in the answers.

Answer (score 5):

Controller using a **ng-controller** directive:

- A new $scope is created on `ng-controller` element.
- Explicit view-to-controller connection
- Visible with inspect element, etc

Controller in a **route**:

- A new $scope is created per route on the `ng-view` element.
- The controller can request dependencies defined in the route resolve.
- Optional view-to-controller connection. Recommended to have a naming convention that maps routes to controllers to views.

Answer (score 2):

One of well-known feature of Angularjs is Single-Page Applications.

If you assign ng-controller attribute directly on the page：

```
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
...
</body>
```

you can't switch controllers easily for other tasks.

So, use route to switch controllers is one of important step in learning Angular Single-Page feature.

You can have same layout and one different  element by using route and ng-view directive.

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
    }).
    when('/tablets', { 
        templateUrl: 'partials/tablet-list.html',
        controller: 'TabletListCtrl'
    }).
```

If '/phones'

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

will include your 'partials/phone-list.html' template
and set 'PhoneListCtrl' as div controller

The same：

If '/tablets'

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

will include your 'partials/tablet-list.html' template
and set 'TabletListCtrl' as div controller

This is the difference between two.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-view` is the cause of the difference. You can't really do this

```
<div ng-view ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
```

As you'd need to change that controller as the route changed. So basically the router does that for you, and uses the controller you specified when you defined your routes.

You probably can do this:

```
<div ng-view>
```

and then in your template:

```
<div ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
```

and leave out the controller declaration in your routes. Which I suspect would have essentially the same effect, although I've never tried that. Probably better to go with convention here though.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st case the controller is **directly** on the page.

Once they change it, that controller is only on the page if the route is `/phones` otherwise it is some other controller based on some other route.

Answer (score -1):

Yes - the change is this:

if you want to display a specific controller on the page, you can use

```
<body ng-controller>
```

BUT

if you want to do routing (application with more than one controller) - you will need to use routing + change the body to:

```
<body ng-view></body>
```

Comment: When I use the ng-view attribute I get an error that the maximum stack size is exceeded.