# Why does AngularJS send double network requests?

Tags: angularjs

I have the code shown below in a controller for an AngularJS Single Page Application.  When this page runs and I check Developer Tools Network (in IE, Chrome, and Firefox) it always shows 2 successful GET calls to Tables, and two empty OPTIONS calls to Tables.  Why are there 2 GET calls?  Is that normal or did I do something wrong in my code?  Also, why does it issue the 2 OPTIONS calls?

```js
"use strict";

app.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.$parent.Title = "Admin";

    var url = $scope.$parent.BaseUrl + "Tables";
    $http.get(url)
        .then(function mySuccess(response)
        {
            $scope.MyTables = response.data;
        });
});
```

Comment: You may have defined your controller more than once...

Comment: may be you use "resolve" in navigation, the best way to find the issue is to set "debugger" before you call $http service

Comment: The OPTIONS requests are probably caused by CORS, i.e. you'res sending requests to a host/port other than the one where the scripts come from.

Comment: JB, I am calling EnableCors.  Does that account for the OPTIONS call?

Comment: M.Doye, I didn't intend to define the controller more than once.  In the html page I have <div ng-controller="AdminController">.  I thought I need to name it in the html page and then declare it again in the controller.  Is that wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has happened to me in the past, the issue was that I had defined my controller twice, once in the route:

```
.state('app.state', {
  url: '/state',
  controller: 'SomeCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/state.html'
})
```

and then defined it again in my view HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl"></div>
```

As far as I am aware, you should only define it in one or the other.

Comment: As noted above in the "controller" page I have app.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http)
and in the html page I have <div ng-controller="AdminController">.  Should I remove the ng-controller in the html page?  I thought it needs both to work?

Comment: If you have defined it in your route, you don't need to add it to the HTML again

Comment: I removed the ng-controller in the html page and I tried it.  It works with only one network GET call (and one OPTIONS call).  So I have marked your answer as the solution.  Now I am confused about how AngularJS defines its controllers.  I thought it needed to be marked in the html page so that it would know what part of the page is controlled by that controller.

Comment: You can add it to your HTML if you prefer, and remove it from the route, it really depends on your app structure, but here is a pretty simple explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21434352/3055401

Comment: M.Doye - Thanks but that link just raises more questions in my mind.  In the "route" I have .when('/Admin', { templateUrl: 'App/Views/Admin.html', controller: 'AdminController' }), then in the "controller" I have app.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http) {...}, and I used to have <div ng-controller="AdminController"> in the page.  I still don't see how they can work together if I remove one of them, but I removed the ng-controller attribute and it seems to be working.